# Simple demonstration of using pyparsing's indentedBlock recursively

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to use `indentedBlock` in pyparsing (which looks awesome to me) to dissect some nested indentations, but am struggling a bit with comprehending its description in the API reference (or the more specific examples under http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com or the mentioning in [How do I parse indents and dedents with pyparsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547944/)).

Could someone please point me to a concise demonstration or explanation of how to use `indentedBlock` recursively, or maybe provide one here? E.g., how would we convert something YAMLish like...

```
- a1_el
    - b1_el
        x1_attr: 1
        x2_attr: 2
    - b2_el
        - c1_el # I am a comment
    - b3_el
        x1_attr: 1
```

...into some XML representation such as ...

```
<a1_el>
    <b1_el x1_attr="1" x2_attr="2"/>
    <b2_el>
        <c1_el/><!-- I am a comment -->
    </b2_el>
    <b3_el x1_attr="1"/>
</a1_el>
```

...with `indentedBlock`? (Also: In what practical situations would I need the different otpions for the `indentStack` parameter?). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit old, but here's a partial answer:

```
from pyparsing import *

COMMENT   = pythonStyleComment
OPCOMMENT = Optional(COMMENT)
IDENT     = Word(alphas, alphanums + '_')

attribute    = IDENT + Suppress(':') + Word(alphanums) + OPCOMMENT
element      = Suppress('-') + IDENT + OPCOMMENT
elementBlock = Forward()
blockContent = attribute|elementBlock|COMMENT
elementBlock << element + Optional(indentedBlock(blockContent, [1]))
```

I've assumed that elements can contain both attributes and elements in arbitrary order. `elementBlock` will parse the whole tree.

It showcases the use of `indentedBlock` so, to make it short, it doesn't allow for comments outside the tree, and it will accept only one root element (not a problem for XML...)

About `indentStack`: it keeps a list of the current number of indented levels and the last element of the list shows the current indent column. As the documentation points out, all the statements on a grammar with nested blocks using indentation should share the same list. As there's only one, I've just created it straight in the call to `indentedBlock`.

I leave turning the result into XML as an exercise for the reader :-P

Comment: This seems to strip the indentations down nicely, and requires little code! (BTW: Should the default value of the second `indentedBlock()`-parameter not maybe be defined as `[1]`? Do we not expect to just require `[1]` in most instances? Why do people frequently seem to explicitly define an `indentstack` variable before invoking `indentedBlock()`?)

Comment: Well, having `indentstack` as a separate variable allows you to keep track of it out of the library parsing code. Also, you could argue that it's "better programmin". But I know how the stack is going to be used internally (had a look in the code), so I just decided I didn't need a variable here, and I passed it straight as an argument. You can do as you please :)